# Oracle database - Trace NLS changes

Tags: oracle

I have a web application with a connections pool. So my connections are shared between all users.
It happens that an NLS parameter (NLS_SORT for example) changes for a connection. As I can't find out where this change comes from, I'm wondering if it isn't possible for Oracle to warn me when a change occurs. Some kind of trigger or specific trace.

Comment: A 10046 trace would be too expensive, and as far as I know `ALTER SESSION` cannot fire a trigger (it appears to be exempted from the normal DDL trigger even though any `ALTER` is normally considered DDL. Perhaps because it doesn't modify the dictionary but only memory structures it technically isn't). Auditing may be your only option. `audit alter session` then query `dba_audit_trail`.

Comment: You may also try to look for connection tagging capabilities for your backend similar to what is described in [Session Pooling and Connection Pooling in OCI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnoci/session-and-connection-pooling.html#GUID-DFA21225-E83C-4177-A79A-B8BA29DC662C) or [Universal Connection Pool Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjucp/overview-labeling-ucp-connections.html#GUID-566DB81D-1930-4B98-A7DC-E2DADF9B9C6D)

Comment: Thank you @PaulW, unfortunately, a quick test with `audit alter session` didn't work. After creating the Policy, starting it up and running an `alter session set NLS_SORT='FRENCH'` in another session, nothing appeared in the `dba_audit_trail` view/table.

Comment: Thank you @astentx, but I can't find anything like it in the library I use (Devart - DotConnect for Oracle).

Comment: `audit` would put rows in `dba_audit_trail`. A *policy* would put them in `unified_audit_trail`. It is also possible that `NLS_SORT` does not require the `alter session` privilege and so would not be audited, whereas other `alter session` uses would. If that's the case then auditing won't work after all.

Comment: @PaulW that's exactly it. I checked, an `alter session set nls_xxx` does not require the `alter session` privilege.

Comment: Maybe you should add to your front-end code an explicit alter session to set your nls_* parameter(s) to the correct values before doing any queries? That way you never run into a situation where one connection messes up another one sharing the same session. Or, disable shared server/MTS and use standard dedicated connections. I have a database that gets nearly 4,000 connections per minute from different sources and by disabling auditing, the update of last logon in aud$, and by using many listeners on different ports with increased concurrency limits, dedicated connections are fast enough.